# Forms' focus malfunctioning when both have ribbon

Tags: delphi, focus, ribbon

I encountered yet another problem with ribbon. When I have two forms (one of them is main) and I put ribbon on both of them, they behave strangely. When I open the second form by `Form2.Show;`, every time I click a ribbon menu button on the second form, it loses focus and the main form gets it.

This happens at pure blank project, so what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Here is a video, just in case: [Watch YT](http://youtu.be/A0tEG_2IOJs)

And to be clear, the `Action1` button has **only** `Caption:='a';` code.

Comment: You're only supposed to use one ribbon control in your application, and it should be on the main form. Did you read the MS guidelines for using the Fluent Interface (which you agreed to abide by during the installation of Delphi)?

Comment: I didn't. I'm trying to look it up now, because I need a separate form (with the same design) and I can't think of a way to do it with only one ribbon (hopefully the guidelines will cover it)

Comment: @Magicmaster, If you really need to switch between 2 identical forms, I would suggest you rearchitect your application to have 1 MainForm with the ribbon hosting either SubForm1 or SubForm2. SubForms could be embedded Forms, Frames or other containers like Panels or Pages.

Comment: [Office UI Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx). :) Took a while to find it, I agree.

Comment: Also, see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403323/delphi-xe-tribbon-actions-always-send-focus-to-mainform), especially the accepted answer.

Comment: @François, the two forms aren't identical. You can think of it as the main form being a pictures gallery with some ribbon options and actions and the second form being a picture editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ribbon control assumes that there is only one per application, and misbehaves if it is not the only control. You could try to modify the Ribbon.pas code, but it is doing some hacks that probably rely on Ribbon.Parent being Application.MainForm only.